# Некорректно отрабатывает скрипт,в чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть список дропдаунов(Bootstrap3).Код одного из них:

```
<li class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 filter-item">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="dropdown widget">
                        <button class="dropdown-filter widgettitle title dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >
                            <span class="filter-name">SORT BY</span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu product-categories">

                            <li class="cat-item">
                                Item1
                            </li>
                            <li class="cat-item">
                                Item2
                            </li>
                           <li class="cat-item">
                                Item2
                            </li>                                                                                   
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Задача при открытии дропдауна по клику,придать ему обводку сверху,слева и справа. Напилил следующий скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

               $(".filter-item .sidebar .dropdown", this).on("click", function(){

                    $(".filter-item .sidebar .dropdown").each(function(){
                         $(this).find("button").css ('border', '1px solid transparent'); // В данном цикле очищаются границы у всех 3 дропдаунов(без него если открыть один дропдаун,потом кликнуть на другой, у кнопки первого остаются границы)
                    });
                    $(this).find("button").css ({'border-top': '1px solid #cccccc',
                                                                           'border-left': '1px solid #cccccc',
                                                                            'border-right': '1px solid #cccccc'
                                                                            });// Здесь по задумке должны присваиваться границы кнопке
                    if( !$(this).hasClass('open') ) {

                        $(this).find("button").css ('border', '1px solid transparent');
                    }
               });// Тут я проверяю,если дропдаун открыт. Если закрыт,то границ быть не должно

        });
```

К сожалению, отрабатывает код не так как хотелось бы. При клике на кнпоку дропдауна,он открывается,но кнопка не получает border. Когда закрываю дропдаун, границы появляются(ощущение,что он в любом случае попадает в if).В чем ошибка?

Comment: Добавьте [mcve]

Comment: А почему с помощью css не сделаете? Зачем вам такой большой код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слишком много кода для решения такой задачи.

Намного проще задать стили в css:

```css
.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="dropdown widget">
    <button class="dropdown-filter widgettitle title dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
           <span class="filter-name">SORT BY</span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu product-categories">
      <li class="cat-item">
        Item1
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item">
        Item2
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item">
        Item2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно документации - [подробнее](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns), я использовал действие `show.bs.dropdown`, когда вызвано действие показа. И соответственно `hide.bs.dropdown` при закрытии дропдавна.

```js
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').css({
    "border-top": "solid 2px red",
    "border-right": "solid 2px red",
    "border-left": "solid 2px red"
  });
});

$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').css({
    "border": "solid 2px transparent"
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    button {
      border: solid 2px transparent;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 filter-item">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="dropdown widget">
        <button class="dropdown-filter widgettitle title dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
           <span class="filter-name">SORT BY</span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu product-categories">
          <li class="cat-item">
            Item1
          </li>
          <li class="cat-item">
            Item2
          </li>
          <li class="cat-item">
            Item2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</body>

</html>
```

> `show.bs.dropdown`    This event fires immediately when the show instance
>   method is called.
>   `hide.bs.dropdown`    This event is fired immediately when the hide
>   instance method has been called.

Comment: В вопросе же ясно видно, что рамка должна быть у кнопки, а не у списка

Comment: @Cheg, вот теперь вроде то что надо:)

Comment: @Cactus, логичнее, наверное, сразу задать бордер прозрачный, а потом выставлять только цвет, что бы не скакало ..

Comment: @Cactus, я предлагаю сразу в стилях задать `.dropdown-toggle { border: 2px solid transparent; border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px; }`, а при клике просто задавать цвет ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev, да уже обновил, спасибо за совет, не сразу допер))